# Insert today's date at the end of a text file - using bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, text-processing, date

I have a text files that is generated through daily running bash script - I want to append a date field into that text file - how can I achieve it ?

```
Name   NUM_OF_USERS

A------10

B------20

**date--29/05/2019**
```

The `---` is just to represent the question well (showcase table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add

```
 date +"date--%d/%m/%Y" >> file.txt
```

to the report generation script.